# Multiply dataframe column by list of scalars and create a new column for each multiplication

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
                  Date     Date.1 SYMBL   TF    Pattern  ...    Stop Risk Amount  GAP LVL  Actual / Back Test  Notes
0             00:00:00 2022-12-12  QCOM   5M  Buy Setup  ...  117.46        0.45      NaN              Actual    NaN
1  1900-01-01 00:00:00 2022-12-12  QCOM   5M       0.84  ...  117.46        0.45      NaN           Back Test    NaN
2  1900-01-02 00:00:00 2022-11-29  FUTU  15M  Buy Setup  ...   58.15        0.63      NaN              Actual    NaN
```

I want to take the column "Risk Amount" and multiply it by a list `l = [2, 3, 4, 5]` and store each multiplication in a new column `c2`, `c3`, `c4`, `c5` corresponding to each digit in the list.

For example, column 2 `c2` should look like:

```
c2
0.9   # 0.45 * 2
0.9   # 0.45 * 2
1.26  # 0.63 * 2
```

and column 3 `c3` should look like:

```
c3
1.35   # 0.45 * 3
1.35   # 0.45 * 3
1.89   # 0.63 * 3
```

What I tried to do:

```
# This allows us to iterate over a list of numbers [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ..., 9.9, 10]
steps = [ i for i in np.linspace(0.1, 10, 100) ]
for i in np.linspace(0.1, 10, 100):
    column_title = f"c{i:.1f}"
    df[column_title] = df_long["Risk Amount"] * i
```

but this gives the following warning

```bash
PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
```

Comment: Have you tried doing what the message recommends? Create a 1-column dataframe for each i, append to a list, and use pd.concat at the end.

Comment: @ndr You're right. That worked

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new dataframe using list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={f'c{i:.1f}': [i * _ for _ in df_long['Risk Amount'].values] for i in np.linspace(0.1, 10, 100)})
```